# Chromium / Puppetter: hiding the URL bar

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to show a Chromium window. However, I would like to hide the address bar (i.e.: where you can input the URL) so that the user cannot navigate away from the page I've set.

Is this possible? I've tried passing the `--kiosk` command line argument, but this forces the browser to go fullscreen, which I don't want, I still want it to be in a window. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following **as long as [chromium supports Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)**,

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--app=http://example.com'] });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

What's happening:

- The `--app=` argument will make it open in app mode (not fullscreen, no url bar, it's a window etc.).
- `browser.pages()` will return the current open pages in an array.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, although it forces you to open a page immediately at launch . Is there any way to open like this but on a "blank" page? (I tried '--app=about:blank' but that doesn't work, only "real" urls seem to work with this method)

Comment: you can try using the ` --no-startup-window` so it won't open the default page